# What happens when a conductor gains potential, but is not completing a circuit

Tags: voltage, electron, conductors

I asked this on the physics stack initially, but I think it could also be appropriate here.

I am not confused about how a conductor gains the same potential as the lead it is connected to (in the case of a battery), what I am confused about however, is what exactly is happening.

Lets take a conductive copper wire and touch it to the negative lead on the battery and leave it at that. I have been taught that essentially, the free electrons have no path to take, so even though there are more of them, they don't disperse through the conductor unless there was potential on the other end of the conductor (excess holes).

I am looking to understand what happens at the atomic level when a conductor gains a potential, but is not a completed circuit yet. For instance, in *semi-conductor theory* a conductor attached to the positive lead of a battery will repel "holes" at the other end.

Do they somehow disperse to the other end?

Comment: You're assuming that the conductor gains potential even though it isn't part of a circuit. Since it's impossible to measure the potential without creating a circuit, then can it actually ever exist under that condition?

Comment: If you attach the conductor to the positive terminal, simply the electrons in conductor will be sucked in by positive terminal of battery. This will create absence of electron on conductor, which represents holes. So the conductor will gain positive charge.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You __can__ measure potential without creating a circuit by measuring the electrostatic force. Perhaps you meant that "potential" can only be measured as an energy difference between two points?

Answer (score -3):

Lets understand whats the meaning of potential:

**Potential means lack of charged particles. Positive potential means lack of electrons. So negative potential means lack of holes.**

Now when you connect a copper conductor to a negative terminal of a battery:-

The conductor has no charge on it. So its at zero potential. The negative terminal of battery however, lack of holes. If you consider following diagram, you will understand that you are connecting two objects with different potential.

[image]

- **BEFORE** Copper has free electrons. But when an electron moves from valance state to conduction state, it leaves behind a hole i.e. absence of electron. Hence in a conductor, both holes and electrons are present. But at any given moment the sum of holes and electrons is zero, which means there is no charge on the conductor.
- **AFTER** Now when battery negative terminal is in contact with conductor, the holes on the other side try to attract the excessive electrons on the battery. So electrons move from battery negative terminal to conductor. Thus a current is formed for a minute time. Now the conductor also has excessive electrons. So these electrons starts opposing the electrons flowing from battery. The electron flow stops when the potential of conductor is equal to potential of negative terminal.

Thus the conductor acquires negative potential.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Probably a wrong answer but perhaps just misleading. Potential does __not__ mean a lack or imbalance of charged particles; it is a measure of the relative energy of the charge carriers. The charge distribution in wire does not change when you connect it to a battery terminal; an __electric field__ is necessary to do that. __The potential of a conductor is not defined/determined by the amount of "charge" on it.__ Electrons cannot flow out of the negative terminal of a battery unless the same number flow into the positive terminal.

Comment: So it would be the same with magnetic induction then too? Like an AC generator? The coil has **charge** but if it is not in a complete circuit there is no electric field and no electron flow?

Comment: @JoeHass I think there is some charge that occurs in these situations because no conductor nor battery is perfect.  There are parasitic capacitances.  Typically we have the privilege of ignoring them, because they play such a small role, but in situations like this, I believe they do play a part.  These mechanics become important in Van de Graffe generators (which are structured using well placed insulators to make this transfer of charge tangible and easier to model).